# How feasible to bind mac address and ip address to block unwanted sites?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking

I'm  network admin in educational institute , We are coming with a strategy to monitor/block unauthorized Network  access  such as (news/social network/entertainment...etc) from students.
till now we used professional firewall service to achieve the same.
On the other hand now we've decided to try some home-grown strategy to  figure out the issue,  so We're thinking of binding ip address and mac address of a  particular station and 
based on that giving various access level for vagarious users (authority).

What could be advantages/disadvantages of above mentioned strategy, considering that  we have 
around 5k different machines and we're using sub-netting to allocate ip's.

Comment: You could do this by changing your DNS settings to use [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com)'. Once configured, you can categorically block access to certain sites.

Comment: @happy_soil we're interested in home grown solution,paid/professional service is not a option right now

Comment: if you are subnetting, you will either have to host your solution on each subnet, or you will be unable to use MACs for identifying end user workstations. the MAC will be obscured by the routers connecting the subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You could force everyone to connect through a VPN with user authentication if they are to access the internet. OpenVPN can be run on pretty-much every platform and [you can set it up so that users have to log in with a username/password](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#auth). You could then dynamically set up filters based on the user who has logged in.

For instance, you could have a daemon monitor the OpenVPN logs, and whenever someone connects, it would modify the filters for their IP address (also shown in the logs).